# placing items into a panel with gridlayout

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, grid-layout

Hey everyone I am trying to draw a checkerboard in Java with GUI. I have created a square class for the squares of the game board.

Square Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Square extends JPanel {

private int width = 80;
private int height = 80;
private int x,y;
private Color color;

public Square(int x, int y, Color color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
}

public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    //setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawRect(x,y, width,height);
    graphics.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
}
}
```

Basically I wanted to create a panel with grid layout of 8 by 8. Then add square objects grid layout panel. I want the first row to contain red,black,red,black,red,black,red,black squares and the second row to contain black,red,black,red,black,red,black,red squares.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,8));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
    panel.setBackground(Color.green);

    Square redsqr1 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr1 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr2 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr2 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr3 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr3 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr4 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr4 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);

    Square redsqr5 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr5 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr6 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr6 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr7 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr7 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);
    Square redsqr8 = new Square(0,0, Color.RED);
    Square blksqr8 = new Square(0,0, Color.BLACK);

    panel.add(redsqr1);
    panel.add(blksqr1);
    panel.add(redsqr2);
    panel.add(blksqr2);
    panel.add(redsqr3);
    panel.add(blksqr3);
    panel.add(redsqr4);
    panel.add(blksqr4);
    panel.add(blksqr5);
    panel.add(redsqr5);
    panel.add(blksqr6);
    panel.add(redsqr6);
    panel.add(blksqr7);
    panel.add(redsqr7);
    panel.add(blksqr8);
    panel.add(redsqr8);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

When I run the program I  get the output  [image: PROGRAM OUTPUT HERE]

Just curious as to why the output is placed in 2 columns with big space between each square. How would i get them to stay side byside on one row to have the first row to containing red,black,red,black,red,black,red,black squares and the second row to containing black,red,black,red,black,red,black,red squares.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't add all the 64 needed squares to the layout. So the layout cells would be stretched to fill all the space. As the result the output would be messy. Moreover, it's a good idea to set the horizontal and vertical gaps to `0`. One more hint is by calling `JFrame#add` it will add the component to the contentPane and there is no need to get the contentPane to add something to a `JFrame`. In addition an intermediary `JPanel` is not needed between the underlying `JFrame` and the `Square`s.

Also I changed the main method a little to reduce the hardships of creating and adding the `Square`s to the output frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            frame.add(new Square(0, 0, (i+j)%2==0 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK));
        }
    }   

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Sorry my my late reply. It worked great the day I received your help then when I looked at it almost a week later I tried to implement the sqaures as a jLayeredPane and I messed it all up and the sqaures dont form a checker board anymore. Just one sqaure is painted.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy that helped. In StackOverFlow typically when an answer helps you, you may check the green check mark on the left side of that answer, to mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: Also for the `JLayeredPane` it can be another question with a [MCVE] which can receive a sooner and better help.